# When the cursor of the input is not visible in version 13.1 of iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, mobile-safari, wkwebview

I am showing the html page using WKWebView. My problem is that after copying and pasting the page in version 13.1 of iOS, I can't see the cursor in the 'input' of a single paste page. This problem seems to occur only in 13.1 cases.

**Problem Reproduction Part**

[image]

**The part where I paste the page from the js file.**

```js
function questionAdd(obj) {

  var act = $(obj).data("role"); // add
  var currentIdx = $("#gameCreateSection .form-wrap").length;

  if (act == "add") {

    var targetIdx = currentIdx + 1; // Number of games to be created

    // Copy the last question append
    var lastQuestion = $("#gameCreateSection .form-wrap").last();
    lastQuestion
      .clone()
      .attr({
        id: "question-" + targetIdx,
        "data-quiz": targetIdx
      })
      .insertAfter(lastQuestion);

    var newQuestion = $("#question-" + targetIdx); // New generation problem

    // Change the ID of the form element (ID redundancy prevention) The ID of the copied element + targetIdx
    newQuestion.find(".form-input").each(function () {
      var elID = $(this).attr("id");
      if (elID == undefined || elID == null || elID == "undefined") {
      } else {
        elID = elID.split("-")[0]; // Import String Region Only
        $(this).attr("id", elID + "-" + targetIdx);
        $(this)
          .prev("label")
          .attr("for", elID + "-" + targetIdx);
      }
    });

    // Other IDs and TEXT processing
    newQuestion
      .find(".form-template")
      .attr("id", "objectiveTemplate-" + targetIdx);
    newQuestion
      .find(".ordered-item-list")
      .attr("id", "objectiveItemList-" + targetIdx);
    newQuestion.find(".example_css").attr("name", "example_" + targetIdx);
    newQuestion.find(".form-input").val(""); // Initialize data entered for replication issues

    $("#objectiveItemList-" + targetIdx)
      .find("li")
      .remove(); //clear existing viewlist
    $("#objectiveItemList-" + targetIdx).html(
      '<li><input type="text" class="form-input example_css" name="example_' +
      targetIdx +
      '" placeholder="Please enter a view" onkeyup="form_keydown(this)"></li>' +
      '<li><input type="text" class="form-input example_css" name="example_' +
      targetIdx +
      '" placeholder="Please enter a view" onkeyup="form_keydown(this)"></li>'
    );

    // create slide
    if (
      slideSection == "undefined" ||
      slideSection == null ||
      slideSection == undefined
    ) {
      // call up the slide if there is no history of slide generation.
      slideSection = $("#gameCreateSection").bxSlider({
        infiniteLoop: false,
        controls: false,
        pager: false,
        slideMargin: 10,
        touchEnabled: false
      });
    }
    // Go to Added Slides
    var moveTarget = slideSection.getSlideCount();
    slideSection.goToSlide(moveTarget - 1);
    sliedeInx = sliedeInx + 1;
```

The cursor of the input seems to be visible in the other version. You can also view the input cursors in version `13.3` or `12.4` and `11.4`

Has anyone solved the same problem as me?

This is bug??

Comment: What is '$' here? I remember a plugin framework that used it but subsequently got binned in a later Swift version as it wasn't' part of the public API.

I just did a search on Swift $ and got no results for that combination. Are you sure it's Swift to allow that?

Comment: @Najinsky This is a JavaScript code. I mentioned in the question but I am using the swift wkwebview.

Comment: Sorry, just been working through a lot of Swift code I got the question via the Swift tag, my brain didn't adjust to the JS (not for the first time).